# Enable sudoing for the logged-in user for one specific prefpane only?

Tags: mac, mojave, sudo

We are running OS X 10.14 VMs hosted on VMWare ESX.
Users log into the VMs via Screensharing app.
VMWare sets the resolution settings to an odd value, so the users would have to use a VMWare command line tool to change the setting to their needs.
Since most users are not capable of using the command line, I installed a PrefPane on the VMs: ﻿﻿
VMware.prefPane. Works pretty good.
In order to set the resolution setting boot-persistent, you need to enter an admin pw, which no user is allowed to.
So I would like to change the sudoers file as follows:
Allow sudo for

- a specified account or the logged-in user
- only for the purpose of changing resolution values via the VMware.prefPane.

Can someone give me a hint on this ...?

Comment: Sudo only works for commands run via a shell. Does your pref pane execute a shell utility in the background? And if yes: which one?

Comment: There's a VMWare ESX for Apple hardware?

Answer (score 1):

You have to script a task to run from the command line for sudo to grant password-less admin rights. It only works on shell scripts and not the GUI password prompt.

The first way to help you is to clarify you have two problems.

1. Make a terminal command into an app that can be clicked so you don’t have to train people in terminal app. (A very valid and worthwhile exercise to solve a general class of problems)
2. Make a command line tool that does what you need - which solves your specific vmware control issue or blockage.

Once you have solved both of these sub tasks, you may or may not need a third question on how to combine two working parts together.

Comment: We added sudoer permission for the vmware tools.

visudo /etc/sudoers.d/monitorsetting

Entry:
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Tools/vmware-resolutionSet

Comment: If you want to edit my answer into shape, please do so @Stefan or I will gladly vote up your answer since you did most of the work to get to a specific solve here.